# Injecting a callable object into a class as a method

Tags: python, inject, callable-object

It is possible to inject a function into a class like this:

```py
class MainClass:
    ...


def simple_injected_func(self: MainClass, arg: str) -> None:
    print(f"simple_injected_func({arg})")


MainClass.simple_injected_func = simple_injected_func
main_object = MainClass()

main_object.simple_injected_func("arg")
# outputs: simple_injected_func(arg)
```

Furthermore it is possible to make an object callable like this

```py
class SimpleCallableClass:
    def __call__(self, arg: str) -> None:
        print(f"SimpleCallableClass()({arg})")


simple_callable_object = SimpleCallableClass()
simple_callable_object("arg")
# outputs: SimpleCallableClass()(arg)
```

I now want to combine these two things and inject a callable class/object as a function into another class while keeping access to object variables and methods of both the `CallableClass` as well as the `MainClass`. (Internally I want to use this to effectively implement method inheritance and inject those methods into a class from another file)

```py
from inspect import signature

class CallableClass:
    def __call__(self_, self: MainClass, arg: str) -> None:
        print(f"CallableClass()({arg})")


callable_object = CallableClass()

MainClass.callable_object = callable_object

main_object = MainClass()

print(signature(simple_injected_func))
# outputs: (self: __main__.MainClass, arg: str) -> None
print(signature(callable_object))
# outputs: (self: __main__.MainClass, arg: str) -> None

print(signature(main_object.simple_injected_func))
# outputs: (arg: str) -> None
print(signature(main_object.callable_object))
# outputs: (self: __main__.MainClass, arg: str) -> None

main_object.simple_injected_func("my arg")
# outputs: simple_injected_func(my arg)
main_object.callable_object("my arg")
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   main_object.callable_object("my arg")
# TypeError: CallableClass.__call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'
```

Why does the second `self` not get correctly stripped in case of the callable object? Is there some way of achieving this?

Comment: 'Internally I want to use this to effectively implement method inheritance and inject those methods into a class from another file'.  I don't think you should do that (TM).  Have you considered a constructor pattern?

Comment: I don't see how a constructor pattern would be helpful here. What I am trying to do is inject multiple related methods into all objects of a class. The object is not one I create in the script I am writing, I am getting it from a module (which I wrote but of which I don't want to touch the source code)

Comment: I suspect I don't understand what you're doing here well enough (hence not making that an answer to begin with).  You do, which is what matters!  If you can do what you want with descriptors all is good.  (The suggestion about the constructor pattern was based on the vague intuition that 'trying to implement method inheritance' is *usually* an X/Y where people are trying to link two arbitrary classes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When methods of an instance are accessed, Python performs "binding", i.e. it creates a bound method. See here:

```
>>> class Class:
...     def method(self, x):
...         return x
... 
>>> 
>>> instance = Class()
>>> Class.method
<function Class.method at 0x7fa688037158>
>>> instance.method
<bound method Class.method of <__main__.Class object at 0x7fa688036278>>
```

The binding is done because methods are implemented as descriptors.

You can also [implement your callable as a descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) if you want to have that behaviour.

In short, you would have to implement a class with at least a `__get__` method. That `__get__` method will be called when either `Class.method` or `instance.method` is evaluated. It should return the callable (which should be a different one depending on whether there is an instance or not).

BTW, to actually bind a method to an instance, it is simplest to use `functors.partial`:

```
bound_method = functors.partial(method, instance)
```

---

All summed up:

```
class Callable:
    def __call__(self, instance, arg):
        print(f"Callable()(arg)")


class Descriptor:
    def __init__(self, callable):
        self._callable = callable

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self._callable
        else:
            return functools.partial(self._callable, instance)


class Class:
    pass


Class.method = Descriptor(Callable())
```

And then:

```
>>> signature(Class.method)
<Signature (instance, arg)>
>>> signature(Class().method)
<Signature (arg)>
```